# What difference does #.00 and #.## make?

Tags: java, decimalformat

Why does the format strings #.00 and #.## produce different results? Consider the following statements.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "#.000" );
DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat( "#.###" );
log4j.info("df: "+df.format(Double.parseDouble("1.2")));
log4j.info("df1: "+df1.format(Double.parseDouble("1.2")));
log4j.info("df2: "+df1.format(Double.parseDouble("1")));
```

the log file read,

```
df: 1.200
df1: 1.2
df2: 1
```

why does #.### does not format?

What does `#` and `0` mean by the way in Decimal Format ?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: Based on the output, isn't it obvious what the difference is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html): 0 represents any digit, where as # represents any digit that is not 0.